# Long-overdue "yum update" has multiple "requires" errors

Tags: centos, centos7, yum, update, webmin

After much neglect of my VPS (currently running CentOS 7.4.1708), I tried to run `yum update`, but after a long list of "Processing Dependency..." lines, the end of the output looked like this:

```
...
---> Package nginx-mod-mail.x86_64 1:1.20.1-9.el7 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: nginx(abi) = 1.20.1 for package: 1:nginx-mod-mail-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64
---> Package nginx-mod-stream.x86_64 1:1.20.1-9.el7 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: nginx(abi) = 1.20.1 for package: 1:nginx-mod-stream-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: libzip5-1.8.0-2.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libzstd(x86-64) >= 1.3.6
           Installing: libzstd-1.3.4-1.el7.x86_64 (MariaDB)
               libzstd(x86-64) = 1.3.4-1.el7
Error: Package: 1:nginx-1.10.2-1.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
           Requires: nginx-all-modules = 1:1.10.2-1.el7
           Removing: 1:nginx-all-modules-1.10.2-1.el7.noarch (@epel)
               nginx-all-modules = 1:1.10.2-1.el7
           Updated By: 1:nginx-all-modules-1.20.1-9.el7.noarch (epel)
               nginx-all-modules = 1:1.20.1-9.el7
Error: Package: 1:nginx-mod-stream-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: nginx(abi) = 1.20.1
Error: Package: libzip5-1.8.0-2.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libzstd(x86-64) >= 1.3.6
           Available: libzstd-1.3.4-1.el7.x86_64 (MariaDB)
               libzstd(x86-64) = 1.3.4-1.el7
Error: Package: 1:nginx-mod-http-image-filter-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: nginx(abi) = 1.20.1
Error: Package: 1:nginx-mod-mail-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: nginx(abi) = 1.20.1
Error: Package: 1:nginx-1.10.2-1.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
           Requires: nginx-filesystem = 1:1.10.2-1.el7
           Removing: 1:nginx-filesystem-1.10.2-1.el7.noarch (@epel)
               nginx-filesystem = 1:1.10.2-1.el7
           Updated By: 1:nginx-filesystem-1.20.1-9.el7.noarch (epel)
               nginx-filesystem = 1:1.20.1-9.el7
Error: Package: 1:nginx-mod-http-perl-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: nginx(abi) = 1.20.1
Error: Package: 1:nginx-mod-http-xslt-filter-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: nginx(abi) = 1.20.1
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Web searches produced questions about specific errors about specific packages, but does that mean I have to figure out what to do about each of these one by one? Or is it safe to use `--skip-broken` like it says is an option?

I also have Webmin, and it says that 391 packages have updates, 35 of which are security updates. It is offering to update them, but can I trust it to not mess things up? I trust `yum`, but...

**EDIT:** I decided to go ahead and run `yum update --skip-broken` and let it do what it could. After the "Installed", "Dependency Installed", and "Updated" stages, this was the end of the output:

```
Skipped (dependency problems):
  gd.x86_64 0:2.0.35-27.el7_9                 libzip5.x86_64 0:1.8.0-2.el7.remi                  libzstd.x86_64 0:1.3.4-1.el7
  nginx-all-modules.noarch 1:1.20.1-9.el7     nginx-filesystem.noarch 1:1.20.1-9.el7             nginx-mod-http-image-filter.x86_64 1:1.20.1-9.el7
  nginx-mod-http-perl.x86_64 1:1.20.1-9.el7   nginx-mod-http-xslt-filter.x86_64 1:1.20.1-9.el7   nginx-mod-mail.x86_64 1:1.20.1-9.el7
  nginx-mod-stream.x86_64 1:1.20.1-9.el7      php-pecl-zip.x86_64 0:1.20.0-1.el7.remi.7.1

Replaced:
  grub2.x86_64 1:2.02-0.64.el7.centos             grub2-tools.x86_64 1:2.02-0.64.el7.centos       grub2-tools-efi.x86_64 1:2.02-0.64.el7.centos
  iwl7265-firmware.noarch 0:22.0.7.0-56.el7       python-parsedatetime.noarch 0:1.5-3.el7         python2-requests.noarch 0:2.6.0-0.el7

Complete!
```

And now the view in Webmin looks like this - 10 packages (and the 7 related  to nginx are considered "security updates"):

[image]

Comment: missing full yum output (especially for enabled repo and enabled plugins), BTW libzstd should be pulled from EPEL which have 1.5.2 (so something wrong with MariaDB repo)

Comment: Sorry, I wouldn't know how to get you a full yum output - the SSH window doesn't hold that much. I suppose I could have directed it to a file, but then I wouldn't have been able to say yes when it asked if it can proceed to do the update. Anyway, I have now run it with `--skip-broken`, so that's water under the bridge (see EDIT). As for libzstd and EPEL, I've never heard of either of them (Google hits seem to think EPEL is a Fedora thing, not CentOS), so I have no idea how to do what you suggested.

Comment: Hmm, I see in the Webmin view that the not-yet-updated packages related to nginx say their source is "Epel", so I guess I do have that - I don't remember installing it, but it has been a long time since I set this VPS up, and I'm probably not competent to be maintaining a server on my own - it's only out of necessity.